# Web Site Designing for Mobile

Tags: c#, css, mobile

I just added printing capability to a web site using a style sheet (ie. @media print, etc.) and was wondering if I could use a similar method for adding support for mobile devices.

If not, how do I detect a mobile device?  My pages are C# (.aspx) and I'd like to scale back the pages for ease of use on a mobile device.

Any advice for me?

EDIT: My wife has a BlackBerry, so at a miminum I'd like to enable our company's web site for that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure how the IPhone/iPod Touch declare themselves when requesting the stylesheet, but for most, using

```
<style type="text/css">
    @media handheld
    {
      /* handheld styles */
    }
</style>
```

should do the trick. It works in the same way @media print does (or doesn't).

For a complete list of media types, see [here.](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html)

Comment: You can also specify the media attribute in a html <link> tag. <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="xxx.css" media="screen" />

Answer (score 2):

Mobile browsers are a real hodge-podge in terms of what they support, whether they follow the "media" attribute on your styles, etc.

I would say aim for [progressive enhancement](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/progressiveenhancementwithcss) (that's one of a series of articles) and make sure that if the browser only understands plain HTML, your content is still viewable and in the right order - for example, you want your main content to appear before the sidebar in the code, since the main content is more important.

A [decent looking resource](http://mobiforge.com/) was mentioned in the article above.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use something like [WURFL](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/), which is a fairly nice database that knows a lot about devices and their user agents, if the other solutions do not work.

And please, remember to reduce download sizes :)

Answer (score 1):

You'd want to have a look at the type of user agent you've got and see if it's a mobile device. The following code would be an example of this:

```
public static bool IsMobile(string userAgent)
{
    userAgent = userAgent.ToLower();

    return userAgent.Contains("iphone") |
         userAgent.Contains("ppc") |
         userAgent.Contains("windows ce") |
         userAgent.Contains("blackberry") |
         userAgent.Contains("opera mini") |
         userAgent.Contains("mobile") |
         userAgent.Contains("palm") |
         userAgent.Contains("portable");
}
```

That should work in most cases! This [link](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/) might help you get more specific too.

Answer (score 0):

The best way of doing all of this is to do it at a server level.

Use a web service to check whether the visitor is a mobile and deliver your output based on this. Use the same URL and perform the same business logic on your application - just change the view layer of your app.

A great option is Wapple Architect (http://wapple.net) - it allows you to do these checks at a server level with some web services and then perform logic and add code if it's a mobile device.

Definitely worth a look.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out! It's pretty cool! http://mobstac.com/developer/

The MobStac API platform is the fastest way to build and manage mobile sites! You get access to developer documentation and API keys.