# CSS: Alternate background image for mobile website?

Tags: mobile, css, media-queries

I'm working on a responsive website, and I have played around with full image backgrounds - it looks great when the website is being resized to iPad size and above, but once it resizes below the 480px threshold (aka: mobile version) it simply looks bad, plus I don't really want people browsing to the website with an iPhone to download those heavy background images to begin with.

How do you reckon this can be achieved? The site is responsive via CSS3 media queries, so of course I can hide the DIV, but is there a way to prevent it from loading the full background images for mobile clients?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: You need to show some more research in what you are trying to do. Posting the code you are using also helps.

Comment: (double comment yes i know sorry hit enter by accident) Also if you are trying to develop for mobile you should have a separate mobile style sheet just for PDAs and cell phones.

Comment: How do you insert the background image? Via an `<img>` tag or via the `background-image` css property?

Comment: Not sure enough about what you're asking to flag this question as a dup, but have you seen this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273283/web-site-designing-for-mobile Also this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3619217/can-someone-please-explain-css-media-queries

Comment: Thanks guys, i'll elaborate: i'm designing in a mobile first approach and the "mobile" site version is achieved via css3 media queries. i'm currently using a plugin to display the full image backgrounds (plugin name- "better backgrounds") the plugin adds the images thru an IMG tag.

Answer (score 1):

check out this post by Harry Roberts that deals with this issue: http://csswizardry.com/2011/07/responsive-images-right-now/

Answer (score 1):

Spotted this thread in my site referrals! I did (I think) exactly this here: http://hry.rbrts.me/ and if you want the code then that's all on GitHub: https://github.com/csswizardry/hry.rbrts.me (specifically: https://github.com/csswizardry/hry.rbrts.me/blob/master/css/style.css#L499)